# Mac version of Python doesn't support UTF-8 in curses module?

Tags: python, utf-8, curses

I'm trying to display a lot of unicode text in my curses application. My development machine is MacOSx 10.6 and I use the default python shipped with Apple.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

When I added unicode text to the screen, the screen all messed up. I tried to Google for solution and other people has suggested to link the _curses module with libncursesw library instead of libncurse library.

I checked my path and I found (see below) in /opt/local/lib

```
libncurses++.a
libncurses++w.a
libncurses.5.dylib
libncurses.a
libncurses.dylib
libncursesw.5.dylib
libncursesw.a
libncursesw.dylib
```

How do I check which library my curses module linked to, and how can I link against other library? Is it possible to do it without recompile my Python?

---

This is kind of embarrassed, but I figure the solution to print unicode properly in my environment. I think at some point time I did install curses libraries from Macports and forgot I have it already.

The problem that the text did not display the first time is because I need to set the locale within my python program. I thought the locale setting would inherit from the shell I'm running, but simply added two lines of code fixed my problem:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"")
```

Though, it's good to know where the python external library lives and how to check them.

Comment: I tried to link the libcurses.dylib in /usr/lib against the one I found in /opt/local/lib, but the result was the same ... So no luck yet~

Comment: Surprisingly, after I added the magic two lines, both python (Apple version) and python2.6 (Macport version) display unicode correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check which other `.so`s a `.so` uses, use `otool -L` -- for example:

```
$ otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_curses.so
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_curses.so:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/libncurses.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.10)
```

This is what I have on my Python 2.6.4 install on OSX 10.5 -- since you're using Apple's own Python on 10.6, the exact location of your `_curses.so` will be different, just do

```
$ python
>>> import _curses
>>> _curses.__file__
```

to see exactly where the `_curses.so` of interest in, then call `otool -L` on it.

Replacing a `.so` on the system-installed Python seems fraught with danger to me -- you *could* break something and end up having to reinstall the OS, etc.  Why not install a Python download from `python.org` instead?

Get both the `.dmg` and the sources for the most recent release of 2.6 (unless you're so adventurous you want to try a release candidate 2.7;-), then you can install the `.dmg` (it will go to `/usr/local`, *not* overwriting the system Python; set your PATH appropriately in your `.bashrc` or wherever to have `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH ahead of `/usr/bin`), then, if your problem persists, you can rebuild from sources with whatever options you want, and replace the specific `_curses.so` in the local install, without disturbing the system directory at all (seems most prudent to me...).

Comment: The python.org installer is usually linked to its own copy of libncurses, not libncuresw, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ned, yep, that's why rebuilding (at least `_curses.so`, but I'd probably find it easier to build the whole thing then move just that module over).

Answer (score 1):

The Apple-supplied Python 2.6 shipped with OS X 10.6 resides here:

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
$ otool -L _curses*
_curses.so:
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
_curses_panel.so:
    /usr/lib/libpanel.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
```

It would be a very bad idea to try to modify anything in `/System/Library` as that could break OS X and/or be wiped out by a system update.  If you need to relink, build your own Python from scratch or start with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), or [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/).

EDIT:

It appears that the current `MacPorts` Python 2.6 install uses `libncursesw` so installing it may be the simplest solution:

```
$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/
$ otool -L _curses*
_curses.so:
    /opt/local/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
_curses_panel.so:
    /opt/local/lib/libpanelw.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
```